# Ubuntu 16.04 , Steam refuses to work (Update 3) [ FIXED ]

Tags: command-line, 16.04, steam

FINAL UPDATE : fixed it on my own.

I'm unable to launch steam , not from its icon in the dash , or from command line. i installed steam from the offical steampowered website since for some reason its not in the ubuntu 16 software center.

i installed it , it seemed to install ok. but it refused to launch when i tried from the dash. This shows what happened when i attempt to launch from command line.

**Update** : i have just recently removed the .steam folder , since im also unable to uninstall steam as well.

**Update 2** : also `LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' steam` does not fix this issue at all , since no games will work nor will steam launch properly  with this fix anyway.

**Update 3** : after a half working steam purge command , i said screw it , and tried to install steam once more , here is the results. attempted to purge , seemed to only half work , so i said screw it , and tried to install it once more , and this is what happened

```
sudo apt install steam
[sudo] password for swaganater: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-21 linux-headers-4.4.0-21-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  steam:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 874 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,662 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse i386 steam i386 1:1.0.0.48-1ubuntu3 [874 kB]
Fetched 874 kB in 0s (2,214 kB/s)  
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package steam:i386.
(Reading database ... 253897 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../steam_1%3a1.0.0.48-1ubuntu3_i386.deb ...
Unpacking steam:i386 (1:1.0.0.48-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160523-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Setting up steam:i386 (1:1.0.0.48-1ubuntu3) ...
swaganater@Kenney4Linux:~$ steam
ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
[2016-07-17 16:06:02] Startup - updater built Jun 16 2014 11:16:02
[2016-07-17 16:06:02] Verifying installation...
[2016-07-17 16:06:02] Unable to read and verify install manifest /home/swaganater/.steam/package/steam_client_ubuntu12.installed
[2016-07-17 16:06:02] Verification complete
[2016-07-17 16:06:02] Downloading Update...
[2016-07-17 16:06:02] Checking for available update...
[2016-07-17 16:06:03] Package file tenfoot_misc_all.zip.b9c015520018655499338cfc2c3a3159e28bbe14 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:06:03] Package file tenfoot_dicts_all.zip.c74a3a9beb77a280cfd8761b901a80ed0f6a3173 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:06:03] Package file tenfoot_fonts_all.zip.vz.b99d15e7a78b99cea4d0abb6c3f3badc0c6ad441_12073430 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:06:03] Package file tenfoot_ambientsounds_all.zip.20ccff954777943069dd2c57576216f5f1db7389 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:06:03] Package file tenfoot_sounds_all.zip.vz.7a3cc0ba5f5309183bca660227b8e0afa9922629_1223056 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:06:03] Package file tenfoot_images_all.zip.vz.5d8dd353339a219454359b8b96832f22383b197f_23726084 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:06:03] Package file tenfoot_all.zip.vz.e0a2fe024bd79e244560aa7b70b005eb85556472_1996073 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:06:03] Package file resources_misc_all.zip.vz.5b8f09b1f407d80780688930b071e340fe22600d_2028216 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:06:03] Package file resources_all.zip.vz.2d17031b733668c91d46c5460e09fe657d5f12d5_5010069 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:06:03] Package file strings_en_all.zip.1079b38e274866fd7f8a52f1bc37a9cfd106e63d missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:06:03] Package file strings_all.zip.vz.647646aa643b76fd21ee5766cc52142308bf855e_1960475 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:06:03] Package file remoteui_all.zip.vz.c3eceeaa19b297032eb8511f44f7f9a49bfdfe01_141152 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:06:03] Package file public_all.zip.vz.c7767235236991fa627ebe4db03f97b171b643b8_792006 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:06:03] Package file bins_ubuntu12.zip.vz.cceda6b84f1293bee16ebc9e8039ff98ffb73893_14829126 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:06:03] Package file bins_pub_ubuntu12.zip.vz.e87445bc7c2dd4f8a3506783c3a5aeb62e8f8bd1_9030239 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:06:03] Package file bins_sdk_ubuntu12.zip.vz.bdf2b7f5d46b352b78fbc7b4782ab8482d6d2459_9441387 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:06:03] Package file bins_codecs_ubuntu12.zip.vz.11b6edae15c9060d91c0730ecbdad978a1bc7f0a_1830793 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:06:03] Package file bins_misc_ubuntu12.zip.9e5c4f09c8cbdfb1b04cc8d0c93da2fee3b09bb1 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:06:03] Package file webkit_ubuntu12.zip.vz.c8fc55b3a22afbfcaff30125993341cb37eca008_31272883 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:06:03] Package file miles_ubuntu12.zip.vz.1b7a19905752a14821fcba42b49fe1a1ed6ba836_299743 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:06:03] Package file sdl2_ubuntu12.zip.vz.f6390a991816501f796aa5cb4c21fc0c13aa4f72_288246 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:06:03] Package file steam_ubuntu12.zip.vz.919f96220bae42fc7bf536ba0d3bc68b02d65de6_1307957 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:06:03] Package file runtime_part0_ubuntu12.zip.6f3376e364f4ce8cf04392af838cded2c254d68c missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:06:03] Package file runtime_part1_ubuntu12.zip.6d3fe6fa3df74ddee0ea944ab024648f3d3179a8 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:06:03] Downloading update (0 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:03] Downloading update (1,437 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:03] Downloading update (5,366 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:03] Downloading update (9,133 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:04] Downloading update (12,954 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:04] Downloading update (16,875 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:04] Downloading update (20,673 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:04] Downloading update (24,216 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:05] Downloading update (27,751 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:05] Downloading update (31,689 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:05] Downloading update (35,410 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:05] Downloading update (39,339 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:06] Downloading update (43,091 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:06] Downloading update (47,018 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:06] Downloading update (50,970 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:06] Downloading update (54,510 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:07] Downloading update (58,090 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:07] Downloading update (61,214 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:07] Downloading update (63,532 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:08] Downloading update (65,917 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:08] Downloading update (67,631 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:08] Downloading update (69,510 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:08] Downloading update (71,743 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:09] Downloading update (73,441 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:09] Downloading update (75,380 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:09] Downloading update (77,602 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:09] Downloading update (79,677 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:10] Downloading update (81,921 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:10] Downloading update (84,829 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:10] Downloading update (86,845 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:10] Downloading update (88,703 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:11] Downloading update (90,704 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:11] Downloading update (92,350 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:11] Downloading update (94,357 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:11] Downloading update (96,594 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:12] Downloading update (98,445 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:12] Downloading update (100,180 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:12] Downloading update (102,523 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:13] Downloading update (105,140 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:13] Downloading update (106,559 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:13] Downloading update (108,226 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:13] Downloading update (109,993 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:14] Downloading update (112,212 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:14] Downloading update (114,191 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:14] Downloading update (116,312 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:14] Downloading update (118,781 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:15] Downloading update (120,983 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:15] Downloading update (122,932 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:15] Downloading update (124,658 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:15] Downloading update (126,421 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:16] Downloading update (127,959 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:16] Downloading update (129,640 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:16] Downloading update (131,699 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:16] Downloading update (133,577 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:17] Downloading update (135,751 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:17] Downloading update (137,248 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:17] Downloading update (139,178 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:17] Downloading update (140,872 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:18] Downloading update (142,577 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:18] Downloading update (144,575 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:18] Downloading update (145,941 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:18] Downloading update (147,583 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:19] Downloading update (149,509 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:19] Downloading update (151,095 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:19] Downloading update (152,822 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:19] Downloading update (154,335 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:20] Downloading update (156,021 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:20] Downloading update (157,819 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:20] Downloading update (159,455 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:20] Downloading update (161,074 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:21] Downloading update (162,582 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:21] Downloading update (164,328 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:21] Downloading update (166,075 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:21] Downloading update (167,701 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:22] Downloading update (169,095 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:22] Downloading update (170,479 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:22] Downloading update (172,400 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:22] Downloading update (174,230 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:23] Downloading update (176,167 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:23] Downloading update (177,937 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:23] Downloading update (179,650 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:23] Downloading update (181,424 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:24] Downloading update (182,997 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:24] Downloading update (184,508 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:24] Downloading update (186,351 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:24] Downloading update (187,519 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:25] Downloading update (189,278 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:25] Downloading update (190,944 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:25] Downloading update (192,636 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:25] Downloading update (194,554 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:26] Downloading update (196,406 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:26] Downloading update (197,925 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:26] Downloading update (199,618 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:26] Downloading update (201,494 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:27] Downloading update (202,460 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:27] Downloading update (204,256 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:27] Downloading update (205,218 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:28] Downloading update (206,179 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:06:57] Shutdown
swaganater@Kenney4Linux:~$ steam
ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
[2016-07-17 16:07:01] Startup - updater built Jun 16 2014 11:16:02
[2016-07-17 16:07:01] Verifying installation...
[2016-07-17 16:07:01] Unable to read and verify install manifest /home/swaganater/.steam/package/steam_client_ubuntu12.installed
[2016-07-17 16:07:01] Verification complete
[2016-07-17 16:07:01] Downloading Update...
[2016-07-17 16:07:01] Checking for available update...
[2016-07-17 16:07:01] Package file tenfoot_misc_all.zip.b9c015520018655499338cfc2c3a3159e28bbe14 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:07:01] Package file tenfoot_dicts_all.zip.c74a3a9beb77a280cfd8761b901a80ed0f6a3173 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:07:01] Package file tenfoot_fonts_all.zip.vz.b99d15e7a78b99cea4d0abb6c3f3badc0c6ad441_12073430 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:07:01] Package file tenfoot_ambientsounds_all.zip.20ccff954777943069dd2c57576216f5f1db7389 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:07:01] Package file tenfoot_sounds_all.zip.vz.7a3cc0ba5f5309183bca660227b8e0afa9922629_1223056 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:07:01] Package file tenfoot_images_all.zip.vz.5d8dd353339a219454359b8b96832f22383b197f_23726084 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:07:01] Package file tenfoot_all.zip.vz.e0a2fe024bd79e244560aa7b70b005eb85556472_1996073 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:07:01] Package file resources_misc_all.zip.vz.5b8f09b1f407d80780688930b071e340fe22600d_2028216 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:07:01] Package file resources_all.zip.vz.2d17031b733668c91d46c5460e09fe657d5f12d5_5010069 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:07:01] Package file strings_en_all.zip.1079b38e274866fd7f8a52f1bc37a9cfd106e63d missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:07:01] Package file strings_all.zip.vz.647646aa643b76fd21ee5766cc52142308bf855e_1960475 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:07:01] Package file remoteui_all.zip.vz.c3eceeaa19b297032eb8511f44f7f9a49bfdfe01_141152 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:07:01] Package file public_all.zip.vz.c7767235236991fa627ebe4db03f97b171b643b8_792006 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:07:01] Package file bins_ubuntu12.zip.vz.cceda6b84f1293bee16ebc9e8039ff98ffb73893_14829126 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:07:01] Package file bins_pub_ubuntu12.zip.vz.e87445bc7c2dd4f8a3506783c3a5aeb62e8f8bd1_9030239 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:07:01] Package file bins_sdk_ubuntu12.zip.vz.bdf2b7f5d46b352b78fbc7b4782ab8482d6d2459_9441387 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:07:01] Package file bins_codecs_ubuntu12.zip.vz.11b6edae15c9060d91c0730ecbdad978a1bc7f0a_1830793 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:07:01] Package file bins_misc_ubuntu12.zip.9e5c4f09c8cbdfb1b04cc8d0c93da2fee3b09bb1 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:07:01] Package file webkit_ubuntu12.zip.vz.c8fc55b3a22afbfcaff30125993341cb37eca008_31272883 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:07:01] Package file miles_ubuntu12.zip.vz.1b7a19905752a14821fcba42b49fe1a1ed6ba836_299743 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:07:01] Package file sdl2_ubuntu12.zip.vz.f6390a991816501f796aa5cb4c21fc0c13aa4f72_288246 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:07:01] Package file steam_ubuntu12.zip.vz.919f96220bae42fc7bf536ba0d3bc68b02d65de6_1307957 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:07:01] Package file runtime_part0_ubuntu12.zip.6f3376e364f4ce8cf04392af838cded2c254d68c missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:07:01] Package file runtime_part1_ubuntu12.zip.6d3fe6fa3df74ddee0ea944ab024648f3d3179a8 missing or incorrect size
[2016-07-17 16:07:01] Downloading update (0 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:01] Downloading update (1,416 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:02] Downloading update (5,344 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:02] Downloading update (9,126 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:02] Downloading update (13,058 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:02] Downloading update (16,961 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:03] Downloading update (20,795 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:03] Downloading update (24,624 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:03] Downloading update (28,119 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:03] Downloading update (32,386 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:04] Downloading update (36,389 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:04] Downloading update (39,917 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:04] Downloading update (43,824 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:04] Downloading update (47,721 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:05] Downloading update (51,795 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:05] Downloading update (56,021 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:05] Downloading update (60,273 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:05] Downloading update (63,941 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:06] Downloading update (68,131 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:06] Downloading update (72,369 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:06] Downloading update (77,286 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:07] Downloading update (82,097 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:07] Downloading update (86,152 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:07] Downloading update (89,679 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:07] Downloading update (93,624 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:08] Downloading update (97,539 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:08] Downloading update (101,440 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:08] Downloading update (104,978 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:08] Downloading update (108,906 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:09] Downloading update (112,809 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:09] Downloading update (116,614 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:09] Downloading update (120,356 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:10] Downloading update (124,925 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:10] Downloading update (128,852 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:10] Downloading update (132,372 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:10] Downloading update (136,341 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:11] Downloading update (141,056 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:11] Downloading update (145,062 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:11] Downloading update (148,902 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:12] Downloading update (151,347 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:12] Downloading update (152,773 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:12] Downloading update (154,611 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:12] Downloading update (156,660 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:13] Downloading update (158,666 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:13] Downloading update (160,595 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:13] Downloading update (162,391 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:13] Downloading update (164,207 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:14] Downloading update (166,191 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:14] Downloading update (168,104 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:14] Downloading update (170,157 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:14] Downloading update (171,861 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:15] Downloading update (173,736 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:15] Downloading update (175,901 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:15] Downloading update (177,509 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:15] Downloading update (179,604 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:16] Downloading update (181,424 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:16] Downloading update (183,312 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:16] Downloading update (185,246 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:16] Downloading update (186,950 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:17] Downloading update (189,193 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:17] Downloading update (191,087 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:17] Downloading update (192,885 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:17] Downloading update (194,900 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:18] Downloading update (196,434 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:18] Downloading update (198,405 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:18] Downloading update (201,488 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:18] Downloading update (203,517 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:19] Downloading update (205,046 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:19] Downloading update (206,648 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:19] Downloading update (208,504 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:19] Downloading update (210,425 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:20] Downloading update (212,310 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:20] Downloading update (214,084 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:20] Downloading update (216,104 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:20] Downloading update (218,076 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:21] Downloading update (219,793 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:21] Downloading update (221,874 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:21] Downloading update (223,662 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:21] Downloading update (225,400 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:22] Downloading update (227,181 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:22] Downloading update (228,812 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:22] Downloading update (230,444 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:22] Downloading update (232,367 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:23] Downloading update (233,856 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:23] Downloading update (235,852 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:23] Downloading update (237,541 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:23] Downloading update (239,537 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:24] Downloading update (241,374 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:24] Downloading update (243,316 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:24] Downloading update (244,520 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:25] Downloading update (245,939 of 245,939 KB)...
[2016-07-17 16:07:25] Download Complete.
[2016-07-17 16:07:25] uninstalled manifest found in /home/swaganater/.steam/package/steam_client_ubuntu12 (1).
[2016-07-17 16:07:25] Extracting package...
[2016-07-17 16:07:39] Installing update...
[2016-07-17 16:07:40] Cleaning up...
[2016-07-17 16:07:40] Update complete, launching...
[2016-07-17 16:07:40] Shutdown
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
[2016-07-17 16:07:49] Startup - updater built Jul  8 2016 21:43:51
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)


[ Old ]
swaganater@Kenney4Linux:~$ steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

I have checked the forums and other questions here on Ask Ubuntu, and none of them helped get it working.

Is there anyway to fix this , or am i going to have to install an older verison of ubuntu?

Comment: Hello!  I believe that you have confused who moderators are and who the community members are.  Moderators have diamonds next to their names, like I do.  Looking back at your posts, there may have been some minor disagreements between you and other community members, but no moderators made any comments towards you.  As well, if you believe community members are directing hate towards you or are not being constructive in comments or answers when trying to help you, please flag those comments or posts for moderator attention, and we can take a look and address them as necessary.

Comment: Please don't add "FIXED" or similar indicators to question titles. If you managed to solve this, it would be great if you could post an answer explaining what you did. Otherwise, this question will always remain open.

Answer (score 0):

First you're going to want to completely remove any leftover steam-related files using these command lines:

https://askubuntu.com/a/217875/569100

Then re-install steam using this: https://askubuntu.com/a/556039/569100

If steam still doesn't work after all that, use this code in the terminal: `LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6' steam`

Comment: i even put that in the post , that doest work!!

Comment: You deleted the .steam folder, so the libstdc++.so.6 is gone, you have to purge steam, re-install it, and run that code.

Comment: Check update 3 on my post.

Comment: According to other people having this problem, this code fixed the SteamUpdateUI error: `cd $HOME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
cd $HOME/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak` reference: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2275526