# Steam not disappearing after my attempts to uninstall it

Tags: software-installation, steam, software-uninstall

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 32 bit.

I messed up with Steam and downloaded it multiple times, so I thought that I should uninstall everything.

I ran the uninstall commands as described in [How do I remove Steam?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217872/how-do-i-remove-steam):

```
sudo apt-get remove steam
sudo apt-get purge steam
```

And it said that Steam had been removed and I had to do the rest manually (delete the files).

I went to the home folder, pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and deleted all Steam files and also emptied the Rubbish Bin.

But still when I search Steam it shows up in the applications list. When I right click it I can uninstall but that doesn't make it disappear from the applications list.

Comment: Please post the commands you used to uninstall the application. You  can use CTRL+R to search your command history in a terminal.

Comment: Did you use the third command: `rm -rf ~/.local/share/Steam && rm -rf ~/.steam`?