# Steam error: Cannot create symlink ... Operation not permitted

Tags: steam

When I try to launch a game from Steam, I have plenty of lines of errors appearing in file `/home/adam/.steam/debian-installation/error.log`:

```
tar: files/etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-dejavu-sans-mono.conf: Cannot create symlink to '../conf.avail/20-unhint-small-dejavu-sans-mono.conf': Operation not permitted
tar: files/etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-dejavu-lgc-serif.conf: Cannot create symlink to '../conf.avail/20-unhint-small-dejavu-lgc-serif.conf': Operation not permitted
tar: files/etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-dejavu-lgc-sans.conf: Cannot create symlink to '../conf.avail/20-unhint-small-dejavu-lgc-sans.conf': Operation not permitted
tar: files/etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-dejavu-lgc-sans-mono.conf: Cannot create symlink to '../conf.avail/20-unhint-small-dejavu-lgc-sans-mono.conf': Operation not permitted
tar: files/etc/fonts/conf.d/11-lcdfilter-default.conf: Cannot create symlink to '/usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/11-lcdfilter-default.conf': Operation not permitted
tar: files/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf: Cannot create symlink to '/usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf': Operation not permitted
tar: files/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-slight.conf: Cannot create symlink to '/usr/share/fontconfig/conf.avail/10-hinting-slight.conf': Operation not permitted
tar: files/bin/xdg-open: Cannot create symlink to '/usr/libexec/flatpak-xdg-utils/xdg-open': Operation not permitted
tar: files/bin/xdg-email: Cannot create symlink to '/usr/libexec/flatpak-xdg-utils/xdg-email': Operation not permitted
tar: files/bin/py3versions: Cannot create symlink to '../share/python3/py3versions.py': Operation not permitted
tar: files/bin/pidof: Cannot create symlink to '/sbin/killall5': Operation not permitted
tar: files/bin/pdb3.7: Cannot create symlink to '../lib/python3.7/pdb.py': Operation not permitted
tar: files/bin/ldconfig: Cannot create symlink to '/sbin/ldconfig': Operation not permitted
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/tmp/SteamPVSockets.onP9bA/SteamLinuxRuntime.529d0377491ff888/socket' -> '': No such file or directory
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/adam/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/adam/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
>>> Adding process 20745 for game ID 1224230
pressure-vessel-launch[20746]: Can't connect to peer socket: Could not connect: No such file or directory
>>> Adding process 20746 for game ID 1224230
Game removed: AppID 1224230 "", ProcID 20714 
Uploaded AppInterfaceStats to Steam
Exiting app 1224230
No cached sticky mapping in ActivateActionSet.
```

And then nothing happen, game don't start.

What can I do? I should reinstall Steam?

**EDIT**

I reinstalled Steam and now it's working fine!

[How do I remove Steam?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217872/how-do-i-remove-steam)

And then:
https://itsfoss.com/install-steam-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: Did you run the steam installer as root or yourself?

Comment: As root `sudo apt install steam-installer`

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same error. It won't update client, and won't allow downloading new games. For me it worked by clearing the tmp folder before starting steam.

```
rm -rf $HOME/.steam/debian-installation/package/tmp/*
```