# Steam doesn’t load beacause of missing GTK modules

Tags: steam, gtk, 21.04

Steam doesn’t load anymore. To see what was the problem, I opened a terminal and typed `steam`. I got this:

```
Loaded SDL version 2.0.15-6484190
Gtk-Message: 18:06:27.386: Failed to load module "overlay-scrollbar"
Gtk-Message: 18:06:27.388: Failed to load module "appmenu-gtk-module"

(steam:10167): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:06:27.393: Impossible de trouver le moteur de thème dans module_path : « pixmap »
(This message is repeated many times.)

(steam:10167): Gtk-WARNING **: 18:06:27.400: Impossible de trouver le moteur de thème dans module_path : « adwaita »
Gtk-Message: 18:06:27.401: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Steam: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
Major opcode of failed request:  151
Serial number of failed request:  50
xerror_handler: X failed, continuing
assert_20210505180626_1.dmp[10254]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/assert_20210505180626_1.dmp
/home/guillaume/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh : ligne 771 : 10167 Erreur de segmentation  $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
```

I tried to (re)install the missing modules with:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall canberra-gtk-module
sudo apt install --reinstall appmenu-gtk2-module appmenu-gtk3-module
sudo apt install --reinstall overlay-scrollbar
```

and some variations of these but it didn’t change a thing. I also downloaded from the official site and reinstalled `steam_latest.deb`, but nothing changed.

I totaly uninstalled Steam (https://askubuntu.com/a/217875/269948) and reinstalled it with `steam_latest.deb`, but to no avail.

Could someone tell me what I must do to make steam work?

Comment: Please edit the question and add Ubuntu release/version and also describe to the best of your recollection what you did prior to noticing the issue with Steam.

Comment: @ChanganAuto For the Ubuntu version, I already put the tag 20.10. I think I may have uninstall a few Gnome utilities from the Ubuntu “Discover” app, but I don’t remember which one.

Comment: You can refer to the logs in /var/log/apt/history.log to find out what you deleted.

Comment: As above. And you can try to reinstall the Ubuntu desktop: `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: @ChanganAuto `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` didn’t work.

Comment: @OrganicMarble There’s nothing in my log anymore about deleting some Gnome apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing *pinned_libs_32* and *pinned_libs_64* folders from steam folder.

If you installed the *.deb* package from the official site, you can do:

```
cd ~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime
mv pinned_libs_32/ bak-pinned_libs_32
mv pinned_libs_64/ bak-pinned_libs_64
```

Now try to run `steam`

Comment: I’ll try that once at home.

Comment: It didn’t work. I got a message about pins “rebuilding” after typing `steam`, but the app didn’t launch.

Comment: I think that the other answer is in the right path. Try to reinstall `mesa-utils` and reboot your computer. Here is some additional info: https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/4909

Comment: I tried `sudo apt install mesa-utils` and `sudo apt install mesa-utils:i386` and both didn’t work. `apt` did not find `mesa-utils:i386`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what could be the fix for `mesa-utils` didn't found. But you can try installing Steam via Flatpak. I read that many users solved a similar issue doing that, but for others didn't work and they received the same error. You could give it a try anyway.

Comment: @robertocabribbean Installing the flatpak version worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error is the following. *Steam* was not able to detect a 3D accelerated GPU driver and did not continue.

```
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

Run `glxinfo` and `glxgears` to verify that you have enabled supported drivers for GPU hardware acceleration.

Comment: I’ll do that once I’m back home.

Comment: `glxgears` worked, and `glxinfo` gave me this:

```
name of display: :1
direct rendering: Yes
server glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_context_flush_control, GLX_ARB_create_context, 
    ...
    GLX_SGI_video_sync
client glx vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_context_flush_control, GLX_ARB_create_context, 
    ... 
    GLX_SGI_video_sync 
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_context_flush_control, GLX_ARB_create_context, 
    ...
    GLX_SGI_video_sync
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you recently upgraded Nvidia driver to 465 from the ppa. It is missing the 32bit libraries and has now been taken down, so revert to 460 if using Nvidia from ppa or wait a while for a re-release.

Comment: How could I revert to 460?

Comment: sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-460

Comment: It didn’t work.